# Javascript with thickbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using thickbox which i can't change.

How thickbox work is "what i put in href comes out in a layer"

for example

`<a href="login.html">click</a>`
when i click on link login.html opens in a layer.

Problem statement :

what i want if i click on it login layers opens.

However when i open link on new tab, i want instead of login.html open it should open action.php

how should i do it ?

Comment: I think you need to put `"action.php"` in there first and for the layer clicking (not new tab) jump in there and replace it with a custom javascript function on the click event handler, then calling thickbox handler with the `"login.html"` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem and solution for this is

on href use "action.php" and use tb_show of thickbox on OnClick  event for layer opening :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the page, when it is in an iframe - or the other way around:

```
if( parent.document.URL != document.URL ){
    window.location="login.html";
}
```

When the page is in an iframe (parent.document.URL != document.URL) it will be redirected to login.html